# How to select <input> wrapped in <tr>?

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose there are multiple `<input type=text>` wrapped in `<td>` wrapped in `<tr>`  -

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td><input type=text></td><td><input type=text></td></tr>");
}
```

How to select all `<input type=text>` for specific `<tr>` ?

For example  - chose all `<input type=text>` for the 4nd row .

Comment: can you be more specific on which rows?  First you target your specific rows.. then get the text inputs

Comment: ok  , I edited the question to spesific row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but the first one that comes to mind:

```
var $fourthInput = $('tbody').find('tr').eq(3).find('input[type="text"]');
```

Steps:

1. Start with parent
2. Find items you want to find the nth instance of
3. Apply `.eq()` for n-1 (e.g., fourth instance = `.eq(3)`)
4. Find the inputs within that instance

This is obviously super generic, but should give you a good starting point.

**EDIT**

Just to call out, since others are using the `:nth-child` selector. Per the [jQuery documentation for :nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

*The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements. With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class. With :eq(n) only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.*

This means that the `:nth-child()` selector will also work for what you want, just so long as there are no other children types prior to the `tr` you want (it will search for the fourth child that is also a `tr`, not the fourth `tr` that is a child). The use of the above `.find()` combined with `.eq()` limits your result set to the types you want, and the child number of those types, regardless of other siblings.

Comment: I'm sure the only siblings of a tr can be a tr

Comment: agreed, so that will also easily work in this context. i was merely providing the additional information for future applications beyond the table, not discounting the other answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to access your tr, you can use for example `$('tr:first input')` which chooses the inputs in first row. Or use some classes `$('tr.wanted input')` and so on.

After your edit, for the 4th row `$('tr:nth-child(4) input')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you should be able to just use nth-child.

```
$("li:nth-child(4) input").addClass("newClass");
```

or in your CSS

```
li:nth-child(4) input {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allinputs = $('tr').eq(3).find('input[type=text]') ;
```

This `allinputs` will have all your `input`s with type `text`.
To change the row change the number `3` . Remember: it is 0 based index.

Answer (score 0):

There's many options on how to select a specific row.. you can use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) - which get's the element at that index for the collection which your selector gets - it's 0 indexed

```
$('#yourtable tbody tr:eq(3) input[type=text]')
```

Using [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) which is 1 indexed

```
$('#yourtable tbody tr:nth-child(4) input[type=text]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector returns you a set of dom element's matching your selector. You can access 4nd row simply by :

```
$('tbody tr input').eq(3)
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rkc3D/2/)